# React css layouting inner components

Tags: css, layout, reactjs

Imagine that I have such html code:

```
<header>
  <div class="header__logo logo">
    <img class="logo__img" ...>
    <span class="logo__status"...>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here

- `.logo` - is class that has styles, special for logo component.
- `.header-logo` - has styles positioning logo inside the header.

So in react inside header component I would like to have something like:

```
    <header>
      <Logo className="header__logo" />
    <header/>
```

But I can't since react is not automaticly handle className property.
Here I see this options:

1. Create a div wrapper to the Logo component and add this class to wrapper. As for me it is not an elegant way because it produce a lot of unnecessary divs.
2. Add logic to the Logo component, that will handle className property and append all outer classes to the root div inside the component. This is also ugly, because I have to add this boilerplate logic each time I want to layout a component inside some other component.

What is the react approach for solving such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot provide className attribute to a react Component. If you want to provide custom class to the same component, you can provide the className as a prop to the component which is added as a className in the child component.
I believe u need to do something like this.

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
           <header>
               <Logo customClass="header__logo logo"/>
           </header>
        );
    }
});

var Logo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
           <div className={this.props.customClass}>
              <img className="logo__img" />
              <span className="logo__status" ></span>
           </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted to know or something else.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I have described handling custom className prop in my second option. But I think that this is not a beautiful since I have to add this boilerplate logic each time I want to layout a component inside some other component.
May be there is a pure react approach for layouting inner components. That is what I am asking.

Comment: I believe u need to write this boilerplate logic if you want to reuse the components else you will end up in creating multiple sub components. React currently does not do what you are trying to suggest as of now.